# jquery setInterval inside focus function

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

Hi everybody Im working on a project using symfony2 and jquery, in the add view of an entity, Iused some jquery code to execute some calculations within the focus event, but the focus is not called when i Put the focus on an input, there is my code:

```
var timerId = 0;

    $('tbody>.ligneproduit input, select').focus(function () {
        timerId = setInterval(function() {
            var j = 0, totalht = 0, totaltva = 0, totalttc = 0;

            //  console.log('remise : ' + remise)
            for (j=0; j < index; j++) {
                // var selectligne = $("#s2id_stock_stockbundle_bonlivaison_lignebl_" + j + "_idarticleentarnat span.select2-chosen").text();

                var sum = 0;
                totalRemise = 0;
                var qte = "stock_stockbundle_bonlivaison_lignebl_" + j + "_qte";
                var prix = "stock_stockbundle_bonlivaison_lignebl_" + j + "_pulignebl";
                var remise = "stock_stockbundle_bonlivaison_lignebl_" + j + "_remiselignebl";
                var total = "stock_stockbundle_bonlivaison_lignebl_" + j + "_totallignebl";

                //console.log('index = '+index);
                var div = document.getElementById(qte);

                if (div) {
                    if (document.getElementById(qte).value && document.getElementById(prix).value)
                    {
                        //console.log('prix = ' + document.getElementById(prix).value);
                        // Do This
                        var qtev = document.getElementById(qte).value;
                        var prixv = document.getElementById(prix).value;
                        var totalv = document.getElementById(total).value;

                        var tva = $('span#tva').text();
                        //console.log('tva ' + document.getElementById(qte).value);
                        sum = qtev * prixv;

                        var remiseV = document.getElementById(remise).value;

                        if (remiseV) {
                            remiseVal = ((sum / 100) * remise);
                            totalv = (sum - remiseVal);
                        } else {
                            totalv = sum;

                        }

                        //console.log('sum = ' + sum);
                        totalht = (totalht + totalv);
                        //console.log('totalv = ' + totalv);

                        //console.log('total ht = ' + totalht);
                        totaltva = parseFloat(tva / 100) * parseFloat(totalht);
                        totalttc = parseFloat(totalht + totaltva).toFixed(2);
                        //console.log('tt = ' + totalttc);

                        document.getElementById(total).value = parseFloat(totalv, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString();

                        $('span#totalht').text(parseFloat(totalht, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString());
                        $('span#totaltva').text(parseFloat(totaltva, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString());
                        $('span#totalttc').text(parseFloat(totalttc, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString());

                    }
                }
            }
        }, 100);
    });

    $('tbody>.ligneproduit input, select').blur(function () {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    });
```

and that is the html code where jquery must be executed:

```
<tbody>
                                {% for prd in edit_form.lignebl %}
                            <tr class="ligneproduit{{loop.index}}">
                                <td style="text-align:center;height: 49px;line-height: 49px">{{loop.index}}</td>
                                <td class="idarticle">{{ form_widget(prd.idarticle,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}</td>
                                <td class="libellearticle">{{ form_widget(prd.libellelignebl,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}</td>
                                <td class="libelleexternelignebl">{{ form_widget(prd.libelleexternelignebl,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ form_widget(prd.qte) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ form_widget(prd.pulignebl) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ form_widget(prd.remiselignebl) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ form_widget(prd.totallignebl) }}</td>
                                <td><a class="remove btn red" title="Remove" idx="{{loop.index}}"><i class="fa fa-eraser"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                                {%endfor%}
```

note that I used setinterval and set timeout in the beginning and this is the code :

```
var index = {{edit_form.lignebl|length}};
    var prototype = $('.form_lignefacturefournisseur').data('prototype');
    // $(".inputdesible input").prop('disabled', true);
    console.log('index ::: ',index);
    selectIntervalID = setInterval(selectIntervalFunction, 1000);
    intervalID1Remove = setInterval(BtnRemoveInterval, 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(selectIntervalID);
        clearInterval(intervalID1Remove);
    }, 2000);

    $('#form_lignefacturefournisseur_btn').on('click', function() {
        var oldForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index)
        var oldForm1 = oldForm.replace(/ligneproduit/g, "ligneproduit" + index);
        var oldForm2 = oldForm1.replace(/idx=""/, 'idx="' + index + '"');
        var oldForm3 = oldForm2.replace(/ordre/, ++index);
        $('#lignefacturefournisseurtr').before(oldForm3);
        $('select').select2();
        // index++;
        selectIntervalID = setInterval(selectIntervalFunction, 1000);
        intervalID1Remove = setInterval(BtnRemoveInterval, 100);
        setTimeout(function() {
            clearInterval(selectIntervalID);
            clearInterval(intervalID1Remove);

        }, 2000);

    });

    function selectIntervalFunction() {
        $('.idarticle select').change(function() {
            // console.log('ttttttttt');
            optionval = $(this).val();
            str = $(this).attr('id');
            idxline = str.substring(38, 39);
            // console.log('idxline  ' + idxline);
            // console.log('str ' + str);
            $('#stock_stockbundle_bonlivaison_lignebl_' + idxline + '_libellelignebl option[value=' + optionval + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
        //    $('#stock_stockbundle_bonlivaison_lignebl_' + idxline + '_libelleexternelignebl option[value=' + optionval + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
            $('select').select2();
        });
        $('.libellearticle select').change(function() {
            optionval = $(this).val();
            str = $(this).attr('id');
            idxline = str.substring(38, 39);
            $('#stock_stockbundle_bonlivaison_lignebl_' + idxline + '_idarticle option[value=' + optionval + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
        //    $('#stock_stockbundle_bonlivaison_lignebl_' + idxline + '_libelleexternelignebl option[value=' + optionval + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
            $('select').select2();
        });
    }
```

any idea why, thanx in advance !!

Comment: Is your first script included at the very end of your `<body>` element, or is it wrapped inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: All right, so it appears your class selector is to blame. You're matching `tbody > .ligneproduit` but it appears the actual class you generate with `class="ligneproduit{{loop.index}}"` has a numeric suffix. Plain `.ligneproduit` will not match that suffix.

Comment: thanx for help, so what should I do to fix it, select tbody tr ..., or regex on the class attr ???

Comment: How about generating a global, non-suffixed class and match that? For instance, `<tr class="ligneproduit ligneproduit{{loop.index}}">`? Then you would not have to change your selector.

Comment: yeah tnx, too simple !!!